# If HTML form was submtited check

Tags: php, html, forms

is `if ($_POST['submit'])` ... same as `if (isset($_POST['submit'])` ... or it means something else? Which one i should use to check if form was submitted?

Is there some way to pull form name?

Comment: All that really tells you is that a form was submitted with an `INPUT` name of `submit`. If you're looking to check that a specific form was submitted, you should use another method. Otherwise, you could check `is_array($_POST)` is `true`.

Comment: i like that one but it does not show that "key fields" for your form are sent and when you check one of keys in post e.g. if isset($_POST['username']) if true it will obviously mean that $_POST is array isnt it?

Comment: Hopefully you're doing validation following when you determine a POST was sent, so determining if a particular field is set is potentially counter-productive.

Comment: If you're actually trying to do/prevent something, and not over-engineering, you might send a calculated hash code in a hidden field, that's stored in a DB table, and when submitted check to make sure the code is set/validates. This is a type of anti-CSRF form spoffing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`. All other methods are flawed. What if you rename the submit button?

Comment: but what if he were to use a get request

Comment: Then he wouldn't be checking $_POST['submit'].

Comment: I am saying if in another case, someone had to use get, what method would work for both

Comment: There is no sense in that, and you can't. You could check $_REQUEST for that, but if God sees that he'll kill ten puppies. You design the form, you put POST in there. If you use GET for the same purpose, your design is wrong.

Comment: if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')... should check both ways, but what if theres nothing in sent? i actually like to see if all requested values been send so i will use e.g. isset($_POST['username'])

Answer (score 1):

To get the form name you can either:

1) use a hidden input field whose value is the same as the form name

2) set the name of the submit button to the form name

The actual form name is not sent in the POST or GET variables.

Answer (score 0):

### [isset](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Determines if a variable is set and is not NULL

### [Boolean cast](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) (same as !empty($var))

> empty returns FALSE if var has a non-empty and non-zero value.
>
> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> ```
> * "" (an empty string)
> * 0 (0 as an integer)
> * 0.0 (0 as a float)
> * "0" (0 as a string)
> * NULL
> * FALSE
> * array() (an empty array)
> * var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
> ```

Pages can have more than one form. It's best to give your submit element a value as well:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="login" />
```

Then in your PHP code, you can:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'login') {

}
```

Comment: Whats the benefit of hidding one input if i can check submit button value too ? e.g. <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Send') {

}

Answer (score 0):

`if(isset($_POST['submit']))` checks if the variable exists or in this case if the key exists under the array and is not null.

`if($_POST['submit'])` will check if the value of `$_POST['submit']` is equal to true (or some other value that evaluates to true).

the second method there, will throw a notice error if the variable is not set. You should use isset to check if a variable is set, that's what it is for.

Answer (score -1):

they are the same but using if(isset($_POST['submit']) or if(!empty($_POST['submit']) are better

Comment: they are not the same. not using isset in this example will throw an error.